# Ipython not displaying image

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I've just started using Ipython/Jupyter notebook and i am following this tutorial http://chrisalbon.com/jupyter/ipython_display_image.html

I opened Ipython on my terminal and wrote

```
from IPython.display import Image
from IPython.display import display
display(Image(url='http://history.nasa.gov/ap11ann/kippsphotos/5903.jpg'))
```

All I'm getting is:
    IPython.core.display.Image at 0x7fc0ab9d23d0

How do I see the image?
Thanks for you help!

Comment: Have you tried in a notebook, not in a terminal ?

Comment: @manu190466 That's the point: Many examples don't make it clear that this is simply not supported from an `IPython.embed()`. It's confusing especially when coming from matplotlib, which works just fine from a terminal. No need to downvote, it's a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, but you need to run it inside `Jupyter`

For more information: http://jupyter.org

Answer (score 0):

I was also expecting that this would work from withing a terminal / `IPython.embed()`.

The documentation of `IPython.display` makes it clear though that this is not supported:

> Display a Python object in all frontends.
>
> By default all representations will be computed and sent to the frontends.
>   Frontends can decide which representation is used and how.
>
> **In terminal IPython this will be similar to using :func:`print`, for use in richer
>   frontends see Jupyter notebook examples with rich display logic.**